# thymeleaf sec:authorize not working in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC project with Thymeleaf and in memory authentication.
In my html I want to display the current user that is logged in and diplay the logout button only when somebody is logged in.

Here is a simple html that should display the username, but is always displays Bob and a text that should only be displayed when somebody is logged in, but it's always displayed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>info.climbinggyms</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>main</name>
    <description>website with an overview of the existing climbing gyms</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
      layout:decorator="layout/root_layout"
      lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Climbing Gyms</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="page-content">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h1>My Climbing Gyms</h1>
            <p>Welcome to my climbing gyms</p>
            <p>This is still under construction, this site only contains dummy data</p>

            <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                This content is only shown to authenticated users.
            </div>

            <span sec:authentication="name">Bob</span>


        </section>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my security configuration:

```
package info.climbinggyms.main;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .logout();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("bleau83").password("{noop}bleau83").roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}user").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I updated my thymeleaf security to springsecurity5 and now it is working

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This seemed to work for me as well although I am not sure why.

Comment: @bleau83 I had the same problem. I defined `xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"` in my html and tried to get value from `sec:authentication="principal.fullname"` but I cannot show the value. I only show it via `[[${#request.userPrincipal.principal.fullName}]]`. How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problem, my `implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'` was missing from `build.gradle` altogether.

Comment: I had the same problem. I defined `xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"` in my html and tried to get value from `sec:authentication="principal.fullname"` but I cannot show the value. I only show it via `[[${#request.userPrincipal.principal.fullName}]]`. How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency if your not sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" working then add following dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, You need update to springsecurity5

> thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5

Comment: This is the same answer bleau83 gave. Consider upvoting the existing answer rather than repeating it.